# React Native with RTK Query Pagination issue

Tags: react-native, pagination, react-native-flatlist, infinite-scroll, rtk-query

I have a React Native mobile application where I'm trying to manage API requests with RTK Query. On the 'Products' screen, I fetch and display data using `getProducts` (infinite scroll). On the displayed data, I have a button for deleting the product (`deleteProduct`). After executing the `deleteProduct` mutation, I want the deleted product to be removed from the screen. I attempted to use `providesTags` and `invalidatesTags`, but since there is a merge part in the query, I couldn't achieve this. Please help me.

```
export const productApi=baseApi.injectEndpoints({
    overrideExisting:true,
    endpoints : (builder) => ({
        getProducts: builder.query({
            query: (page=1) => `url?page=${page}`,
            transformResponse: (response) => {
                return response.data
            },
            serializeQueryArgs: ({ endpointName }) => {
                return endpointName
            },
            merge: (currentCache, newItems) => {
                currentCache.data.push(...newItems.data)
                currentCache.links = newItems?.links;
            },
            forceRefetch({ currentArg, previousArg }) {
                return currentArg !== previousArg
            },
            providesTags: (result) =>
                result
                    ? [
                        ...result.data.map(({ id }) => ({ type: 'Products', id })),
                    ]
                    : [{ type: 'Products', id: 'PARTIAL-LIST' }],
        }),

        deleteProduct: builder.mutation({
            query : (id) => ({
                url: "products/delete",
                method: "POST",
                body: {
                    id:id
                }
            }),
            invalidatesTags: (result, error, id) => [
                { type: 'Products', id },
            ],
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `updateQueryData` inside `onQueryStarted` to manually update the cache entry for that file Check [this](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/manual-cache-updates) out

```
export const productApi=baseApi.injectEndpoints({
  overrideExisting:true,
  endpoints : (builder) => ({
      getProducts: builder.query({
          query: (page=1) => `url?page=${page}`,
          transformResponse: (response) => {
              return response.data
          },
          serializeQueryArgs: ({ endpointName }) => {
              return endpointName
          },
          merge: (currentCache, newItems) => {
              currentCache.data.push(...newItems.data)
              currentCache.links = newItems?.links;
          },
          forceRefetch({ currentArg, previousArg }) {
              return currentArg !== previousArg
          },
          providesTags: (result) =>
              result
                  ? [
                      ...result.data.map(({ id }) => ({ type: 'Products', id })),
                  ]
                  : [{ type: 'Products', id: 'PARTIAL-LIST' }],
      }),

      deleteProduct: builder.mutation({
          query : (id) => ({
              url: "products/delete",
              method: "POST",
              body: {
                  id:id
              }
          }),
          onQueryStarted: async (arg, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) => {
              const patchResult = dispatch(
                  productApi.util.updateQueryData('getProducts', (draft) => {
                      draft.data = draft.data.filter((res) => res.id !== arg);
                  }),
              );
              try {
                  await queryFulfilled;
              } catch {
                  patchResult.undo();
              }
          },
      })
  })
})
```

^ Do this instead of `invalidateTags` so you don't trigger a full reload

The only issue is that your pagination will now be off by one (the next page you load will actually skip one item). So you probably have to add an offset or something to compensate. I'm still trying to figure out myself how to deal with this

Comment: i have tried your suggestions and sadly there was a warning ' WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 2):
Error: [Immer] The first or second argument to `produce` must be a function
Error: [Immer] The first or second argument to `produce` must be a function'

Comment: To deal with the offset after the optimistic update you have to trigger a new request with the latest args –basically `invalidateTags`– but now you will need a better logic on `merge` to avoid duplications.